# How can I see the list of Windows updates that will be installed at restart?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I see on `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update`:

[image]

How can I see the list of Windows updates that will be installed at restart?

Comment: Any pending update that has been installed will finish installing when you reboot.  As for a list, requires you to look at the list, and simply know which updates even require a reboot

Comment: @Ramhound  Thanks,  I had missed that. ( I  used to be empty but it is now accessible  after changing a few  registry keys  to remove "some settings are managed by  your system administrator" ). I'll  remove the question soon  once you read  my comment.

Comment: Franck, your question and Ramhound's comment might be useful to others (you probably aren't the only person with that question).  Think about not deleting it, even posting an answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 sure thing, done!

Answer (score 1):

You can review the list of Windows updates that will be installed at restart (a.k.a. pending Windows updates -> please see comment, I am not 100% sure about it) in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update\View update history`:

[image]

If the list is empty, e.g.:

[image]

here are two possible causes. Cause 1: in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update\Change settings`, you have a message `some settings are managed by your system administrator`:

[image]

In that case, it is possible that one of the settings prevents you from viewing
the update history. To reset the default setting, you can run in a `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate]
```

Cause 2: one of the answers in [How To Cancel Pending Windows 7 Updates](https://superuser.com/q/356574/116475) causes of the Windows update history to be empty. I suspect it is removing the file `C:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml` that causes it.

Comment: Just for clarification, are the pending items just cleanup of updates already installed, or updates that have been delayed until after reboot due to dependencies on other updates?

Comment: @fixer1234 I believe updates that have been delayed until after reboot due to dependencies on other updates or other reasons. I'd be very interested if someone could confirm or infirm though, I am not familiar with Windows automatic updates, just a victim of it.